# First run of Docker -- Running makeitopen.com's F8 App

Tags: docker, react-native

I'm reading through makeitopen.com and want to run the F8 app.

The instructions say to install the following dependencies:

- Yarn
- Watchman
- Docker
- Docker Compose

I've run `brew install` on all of these, and none appeared to indicate that any of them had already been installed. I have not done any config or setup or anything on any of these new packages.

The next step is to run `yarn server` and here's what I got from that:

```
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Not having any experience with any of these packages, I don't really know what to do (googling brings up so many different scenarios). What do I do now?

PS. Usually when I work with React Native I run `npm start` to start the expo-ready app, but the F8 project doesn't respond to `npm start`.

### UPDATE (sort of):

I ran `docker-compose up` which appeared to run all the docker tasks, and I'm assuming the server is running (although I haven't tried `yarn server` again).

I continued with the instructions, installing dependencies with `yarn` (which did appear to throw some errors. quite a few, actually, but also a lot of success).

I then ran `yarn ios`, and after I put the Facebook SDK in the right folder on my computer, the XCode project opened.

The Xcode build failed. Surprise, right? It did make it through a lot of the tasks. But it can't find `FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h` (although that file does appear to exist in `FBSDKShareKit/Headers/`)

Any thoughts? Is there any way in the world I can just run this in expo?

Answer (score 1):

If docker and docker-compose are installed properly, you either need root priviledges or [use the docker group](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) to add yourself:

```
usermod -aG docker your-username
```

Keep in mind, that all members of the `docker` usergroup de facto have root access on the host system. Its recommended to only add trusted users and keep precautionary measures to avoid abuse, but this is another topic.

When docker is not working properly, check if it's daemon is running and maybe restart the service:

```
# systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-02-28 19:41:47 CET; 3 weeks 3 days ago
```

Then create the container again using `docker-compose up`.

### Why a simple `npm start` doesn't work

The [package.json file](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/package.json) shows that those script exists, but it runs `npm start`. Looking at [the docker-compose.yml file](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/docker-compose.yml), we see that it creates 5 containers for it's mongo database as well as [grapql](https://graphql.org/) and the frontend/backend. Without docker, it wouldn't be possible to set up a lot of services that fast. You'd need to install and configure them manually.

At the end your system may be messed up with software, when playing around with different software or developing for multiple open source projects. Docker is a great way to deploy modern applications with keeping them flexible and separated. It's worth to get started with those technology.

Comment: Thank you so much for this in depth answer! Now, it does assume one or two very basic steps of understanding on my part about how to do /anything/ with docker – for example, it looks like I'm not supposed to run that `usermod` command from the terminal, and I don't know where to run it from. When you say "restart the service", I don't know how! `systemctl` is also not found by bash on my system. So I guess learning docker is my project for the day! (unless you have some faster answers)